# git svn clone confusion

Tags: git, git-svn

I have a project in *svn* that is set up as:

```
project
 branches/
 tags/
 trunk/
```

when ever I do a

```
git svn clone -s -r ##:HEAD path/to/svn
```

All I get is a series of file and folders that I believe comes from `trunk` and when I do a

```
git branch
```

all I see is `master` when I should see `master` and `clean` (`clean` is under `branches/`)

So whats going on?

If I do:

```
git svn clone -r ##:HEAD path/to/svn
```

then I get my layout of:

```
project
 branches/
 tags/
 trunk/
```

but *git* doesn't recognise the branches under `branches`. Also `trunk` is also a `branches`....

Any ideas?

Comment: "branch"? the correct top-level directories are usually trunk/branches/tags (note: branchES). This corresponds to --stdlayout (-s) option. Your layout is not standard, so --stdlayout option doesn't work for you. I would recommend to change your SVN repository layout.

Comment: my appoligies it is branches not branch.

Comment: Then I hardly understand the problem. According to this information '-s' works as expected. 'Trunk' has the meaning of branch in both SVN and Git (converted from git-svn), so there's nothing unexpected.

Comment: there is: there is no branches, no tags. under branches in svn is a branch named clean. in git I should see master (the trunk) and clean (from branches/) instead all I see is master.

Comment: I see now. The information here is not enough for solving. What you can do --- have a look, at which revision the branch was created the in the SVN and match it with git-svn output -- to see if there any out about the branch 'clean' found. If git-svn doesn't recognize it, it may be a bug in git-svn (because it seems you do everything correctly). You may also try other approaches of using Git with SVN, not based on git-svn engine like SmartGit (a UI client with SVN support) or SubGit (creates a pure Git interface to the SVN repository, server-side solution).

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your branches were created but you're not seeing them because they are remote branches. Try `git branch -va`. To work with these remote branches you could, for example, create a local branch:

`$ git checkout -b working_from_branch -t clean remotes/branches/clean`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

```
git branch -r
```

...which should show you all remote branches this repository is aware of.  Assuming your branches/ directory is flat (no nested branches, or branch hierarchies), git svn clone -s ought to recognize them automatically.

The reason these don't show up in the default response to git branch is that it is generally bad practice to work directly on a remote branch in git.  When you go to send changes to the remote repository, everything on the remote branch will be sent, no matter what.  By checking out a local tracking branch, you retain the option of removing commits (by creating another local tracking branch, and copying the changes you'd like to send there).  To create a tracking branch, use:

```
git checkout -b master-mybranch -t mybranch
```

where mybranch is the branch you'd like to track.  I use master-* as my own convention, but you can name the tracking branch anything you like, as long as it helps you remember what it is.  Good luck!